# How to iterate the data returned from the response that was an observable

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

Hi All I am new to JavaScript and started leaning Angular. This is the response from the application returned by the Spring Boot Application. I want to know how to interate this UserCred object using ForEach loop.

```
Response from the Server

UserCred {username: "Prawin", password: "password"}
password: "password"
username: "Prawin"
__proto__:
constructor: class UserCred
arguments: (...)
caller: (...)
length: 2
name: "UserCred"
prototype: {constructor: ƒ}
__proto__: ƒ ()
[[FunctionLocation]]: user-registration.service.ts:6
[[Scopes]]: Scopes[2]
__proto__:
constructor: ƒ Object()
hasOwnProperty: ƒ hasOwnProperty()
isPrototypeOf: ƒ isPrototypeOf()
propertyIsEnumerable: ƒ propertyIsEnumerable()
toLocaleString: ƒ toLocaleString()
toString: ƒ ()
valueOf: ƒ valueOf()
__defineGetter__: ƒ __defineGetter__()
__defineSetter__: ƒ __defineSetter__()
__lookupGetter__: ƒ __lookupGetter__()
__lookupSetter__: ƒ __lookupSetter__()
get __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
```

A piece of code that returns the response.

```
  handleLogin(){
    console.log("inside Login");
    console.log(this.username);
    console.log(this.password);
    this.userRegistartionService.postUserCredientials(this.username, this.password)
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(typeof data);
        this.loginService.aunthenticate(this.username);
        this.router.navigate(["application/manage"]);
      });
  }
```

I need to get the data from the response object named "data"

I want to get the username and password in specific. Because it is a response object I am struggling to fetch the data using ForEach loop.

Comment: I can't see an array to iterate anywhere. Why do you want to use `forEach`?

Comment: I need to get the username and password from the data inside the subscribe, I am not specifically looking ForEach though. I just need to get the username and password from the response.

Comment: It seems like you already get it just fine - you can use `data.username` and `data.password` in the callback and do anything you want with it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Yeah I already tried using that, But I am unable to use it. The code doesn't compile.

It shows the below compilation error,
Property 'username' does not exist on type 'Object'.

Comment: Hi, I tried using this "console.log(data["username"]);" It worked, but I don't have any clue. If you know the reason please do let me know. But I am sure I am returning back the object as a response from the server.

Comment: Try declaring `type SomeType = { username: string; password: string; };` and then in your code change to `....subscribe((data: SomeType) => {...`